# Why wasn't Davros exiled by the Kaleds?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

In *Genesis of the Daleks*, the Doctor is forced to try to alter the evolution of the Daleks. Davros is the chief scientist on Skaro. By the first century of the war with the Thals, some Kaleds were mutated and quickly exiled. Davros was clearly mutated because he looks nothing like the Kaleds, so why was he never exiled? And how did he obtain that power?

Answer (score 2):

Although the cause of Davros' appearance has never been explained in any televised episode, audio plays and comics have established the story that his appearance is the result of being injured in an explosion caused by a Thal warhead, not the result of a mutation (and the BBC has made a point of avoiding any official policy as to what qualifies as 'canon', it's up to individual fans to decide whether they want to incorporate spin-off material into their personal headcanon). This was detailed in the [I, Davros](http://www.bigfinish.com/ranges/released/i-davros) audio series from 2006 which delved into his past--the [Doctor Who Reference Guide](http://www.drwhoguide.com/who.htm) has summaries of the plots of pretty much every Doctor Who story including I, Davros which you can find at the bottom of the main page--it's a four-part series, the parts are ["Innocence"](http://www.drwhoguide.com/davros01.htm), ["Purity"](http://www.drwhoguide.com/davros02.htm), ["Corruption"](http://www.drwhoguide.com/davros03.htm), and ["Guilt"](http://www.drwhoguide.com/davros04.htm). The explosion occurs towards the end of the one titled "Corruption", and these stories also go into detail about his rise to power, which you had also asked about.

The [Davros page on the TARDIS wikia](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Davros) also gives a shorter summary of his biography as established in spin-off media, and also shows a panel from a comic titled ["Up Above the Gods"](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Up_Above_the_Gods_(comic_story)), published in the [July 1995 issue of *Doctor Who Magazine*](http://www.alteredvistas.co.uk/html/sixth_doctor.html), which seems to show an image of the aftermath of the explosion--the caption suggests that this is a depiction of the explosion that caused his disfigurement, though I haven't read it and can't find any detailed summaries. But assuming that's correct, this was probably the first source to establish that his appearance was the result of an explosion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The scientists within Kaled society formed an “Elite group”, that wielded incredible influence:

> DOCTOR: Years ago the Kaled government decided to form an Elite group. The best scientific brains in every field.
>
> HARRY: A sort of Think Tank.
>
> DOCTOR: Yes. But **over the years the Elite has become more and more powerful, and now they can demand whatever they like.**

Davros was the *head* of this Scientific Elite. Regular soldiers and citizens affected by the mutations might be banished from the city, but apparently his position of power gives him immunity. Whether that’s because he simply decrees it so, or because the rest of Kaled society believes him too valuable to lose, isn’t clear – but it doesn’t really matter.

Alternatively, it may be that nobody outside the Kaled scientific community know of Davros’s mutations. As Ronson explains:

> RONSON: Well, I must. There are a few in the Kaled government who still have the power to act. If they knew the truth, they would end Davros' power, close down this bunker, finish the Elite.
>
> DOCTOR: Then go to them, Ronson, go to them.
>
> RONSON: **But I'm not allowed in the city. Security here is absolute.**

If Davros entered the Dome with a healthy body, and has suppressed any messages about his health, then nobody would know to exile him because nobody knows that he’s mutated. (And if you were one of his subordinates inside the Scientific Dome, would you suggest it?)